# Eclipse Build Path library jar files based in user home directory

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not having any luck searching for a solution to this problem.

I work with a team that uses Eclipse for the java IDE, and gradle for the project build. We are developing on a linux distro.

One of the Java projects needs to use library jar files that gradle pulls down into the {homedir}/.gradle/cache directory tree.

How do I setup the project Build Path in eclipse, and the .classpath file it generates, to use a home directory variable ({HOMEDIR_VAR}/.gradle/cache/...), instead of hard-coding my home directory (/home/{myusername}/.gradle/cache/...)?

Comment: Did you try using Buildship, the gradle plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good practice to not commit IDE specific project files to version control. Modern build tools (Maven, Gradle) integrate nicely with IDEs like Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA and Netbeans to generate those artifacts for you.

In short, let Gradle build the Eclipse class path for you. That is either via

- [Buildship](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/february/buildship.php) ([Using the Gradle build system in the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html)), the official Eclipse plugin to integrate with the Gradle build system. Easy to use and you can directly import Gradle projects into Eclipse.
  [image: Import existing Gradle projects into Eclipse via Import wizard]
- [Gradle Eclipse Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html), a Gradle plugin that generates required Eclipse project files.

There's no need to fiddle with the class path manually anymore. However, if for somewhat reason this doesn't work out for you, there's a workaround: It is possible to relocate the Gradle home directory and with that the cache directory to a static path. This can be done for example by defining the environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` ([Gradle Goodness: Changing the Gradle User Home Directory](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-changing-gradle-user.html)). With that, it's possible to maintain the Eclipse class path manually and share it with your team.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was thinking this was simply an eclipse configuration issue. We have ".project" and ".classpath" files in our baseline for each subproject, so when a developer checks out the baseline, they can simply "Import..." existing projects into eclipse. It looks like when another developer pushed his changes into the baseline, and I pulled them down, the .classpath file in my development sandbox had his home directory in the .classpath library entries. Maybe there is a better way of controlling the BuildPath with a plugin. I am fairly new to Gradle builds.

Comment: Updated my answer. I highly recommend looking into Buildship first. But since you can relocate the Gradle home directory e.g. via environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME`, the Eclipse class path entry can be fixed for everyone on your team.

Comment: Thanks again. The Gradle Eclipse plugin works for this project. I've now removed the Eclipse .project and .classpath files from the baseline and simply let Gradle generate them for us.